# Deleted local database in DBeaver, still seems active in app but cannot view in DBeaver

Tags: database, postgresql, dbeaver

I have a local database for my app and I browse the records in it with DBeaver. I deleted the database in DBeaver:

[image]

The database still seems to exist because my app is using it and it has records in it, but when I try to read the records in DBeaver I get:

[image]

Is the database still there? How do I get DBeaver to read the records in it?

Comment: It looks like your database "api_repo" was never deleted but the table "categories" was dropped. All assuming you had refreshed the view. Exactly which database did you delete and which one does your app use?

Comment: @Slumdog Nothing got deleted as I have now used PGAdmin to browse the database. I just can’t do that in DBeaver. I deleted that top level database in the images (postgresql)